# Need help doing a git merge

Tags: git

I am working with a collaborator and we are using a remote repo on Bitbucket.

The problem that I am facing is when I push a change to the remote repo. My collaborator is not able to pull in the changes.

When he does a git pull he keeps on getting the following error ..

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:    test.php    
Please move or remove them before you can merge.    
Aborting
```

But that's exactly what I want it to do; have new update files overwrite the old files.

Why do I need to move or remove the files in order for me to obtain the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes would be lost if they pulled in new changes.  Git is *actively* trying to prevent that, so it forces you to either blow away the changes or stash them for later.

Stash the changes:

```
git stash save
```

Then your collaborator can pull the changes into their branch.

If they want to reapply the changes, then they can do `git stash apply` to reapply them on top of the new changes.